Позиционирование слайдов к правой стороне Swiper
Вопрос в следующем, нужно чтобы слайд был в два раза больше по ширине чем сам экран и начинался с правой стороны.
Вот сам макет. 


как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример

"... нужно чтобы..." Кому нужно? Если Вам, то где же ваши попытки приложенные к вопросу в виде кода? Что конкретно не получается?

Предоставление кода в данном примере не несет не какого смысла, мне нужно подсказать параметр который это осуществляет, к примеру, slidesPerView: "auto", с margin-left: auto; для слайда

@EgorGivzegud, "нужно подсказать" - api читайте, изучайте. Если не код, то сделайте описание более понятным, ибо нет ясности того, что нужно. Swiper вряд ли рассчитан именно для такой логики, которую вы показываете. По моим ощущениям, вообще иное поведение для данного слайда нужно, как минимум ощущение того, что тут изображение должно обрезаться к правой стороне, т.е. для данного слайда делается img {object-fit: cover; object-position: right center;}, а это уже не клайдеру относится.

Не мучайте слайдер, просто обрежте картинку на половину и всё
